# What is the best way to inherit an interface without using virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have some class `Base`:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    auto foo() -> void { private_foo(); }
    auto bar() -> void;
private:
    auto private_foo() -> void;
};
```

There will never be and instance of `Base`; it acts only to define an interface and optionally some implementation (here implementation is in `foo()` and it calls a private function `private_foo()` which it is expecting to be defined by its derived classes). `Derived` will be a concrete type and will define the implementations of `bar()` and `private_foo()`. How can one best achieve this without using virtual inheritance?

My initial thoughts were to define `Base` as a class template:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    auto foo() -> void { private_foo(); }
    virtual auto bar()=0 -> void;
private:
    virtual auto private_foo()=0 -> void;
};
```

Then `Derived` can be defined as such:

```cpp
class Derived: public Base<Derived> {
public:
    auto bar() override -> void { // bar implementation };
private:
    auto private_foo() override -> void { // private_foo implementation};
};
```

Is this the best way? Am I correct in assuming that this does not create a virtual function pointer table? Is there a way that is cleaner or more idiomatic? I am aware that I am creating a template class using virtual inheritance, but my impression is that the 'virtual' aspect will be compiled away.

The goal is to create an interface without run-time overhead.

Comment: Maybe try to use a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), aka static polymorphism

Comment: "virtual inheritance" is not the same as inheriting from class with virtual functions. Virtual function pointer table will be created when there are some virtual functions.

Comment: Your `Base` class still introduces a vtable (and the overhead coming with it). With CRTP you just use `static_cast`s from the `Derived` `this` pointer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is actually what I tried to achieve - modifying OPs sample. However, it fails due to `private: private_foo()`. Something is missing. [**Attempt on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/911f65212e75566a). Any idea? (I didn't want `friend class Base;` in `Derived` but I don't know how to come around.)

Comment: With `friend class Base;` in `Derived` it would work: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc46b032f414ca9d). :-(

Comment: @Scheff The major flaw in the OP's question is, that they still introduce a `virtual` function in their example (and thus not get rid of the overhead).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is something I realized and agree on. Hence, I tried to make a sample without `virtual` but keeping `private_foo()` `private` in `Derived` (what I considered as intention of the whole fiddling). However, I gave up with my 2nd attempt ;-) (...but I might've overseen something clever).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ CRTP seems like the correct solution. I presume that `private_foo()` cannot appear in the definition of `Base` and so it needs to be documented that `Derived` must implement it (it cannot be documented by the code).

Comment: @Tintin It will be _"documented"_ since you get compiler errors otherwise.